# Opening a single image

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, python-imaging-library

I'm trying to open an image with size (520,696) but when I use this

```
array = np.array([np.array(Image.open(folder_path+folders+'/'+'images'+'/'+image))], np.int32).shape`
```

I'm getting the shape as

```
(1, 520, 696, 4)
```

The problem is with this shape I can't convert it to image using `toimage(array)`; I get

> 'arr' does not have a suitable array shape for any mode.

Any suggestions on how may I read that image using only (520,696)?

Comment: liliscent's answer will work, but I'm curious, why the nested np.array?

Comment: Probably he tried to adapt an answer that loads a stack of images into a numpy array. Hence the dimension 1 for the stack.

Comment: @Piinthesky is right

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is the additional dumb dimension. You can remove it using:

```
arr = np.squeeze(arr)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your time

Answer (score 1):

You should load the picture as a single picture instead of loading it as a stack and then removing the irrelevant stack dimension. The basic procedure could be something like this:

```
from PIL import Image

pic = Image.open("test.jpg")
pic.show()                     #yup, that's the picture

arr = np.array(pic)            #convert it to a numpy array
print(arr.shape, arr.dtype)    #dimension and data type
arr //= 2                      #now manipulate this array

new_pic = Image.fromarray(arr) #and keep it for later
new_pic.save("newpic.bmp")     #maybe in a different format
```